# Apply a lm() model in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I have a simple linear model saved as a `.rda` file that I would like to import and apply to a set of inputs for a shiny flexdashboard.

My code is below:

````
---
title: "Where Should I Publish My Piece?"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
load('mods/mod.rda') # The lm() being imported
load('sections_list.rda') # A list of sections
```

Sidebar {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Article Info
```{r}
renderText("Tell us a few things about your thing")
textInput(inputId = 'a',
          label = 'What's a number?',
          value = 1000)
selectInput(inputId = 'b',
            label = 'What section are you using?',
            choices = secs,
            selected = secs[1])
selectInput(inputId = 'c',
            label = 'What hour is it?',
            choices = seq(0,23,1),
            selected = 0)
selectInput(inputId = 'd',
            label = 'What day of the week is it?',
            choices = c("Thursday","Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday",
                        "Monday", "Wednesday", "Tuesday"),
            selected = "Monday")
```

Columns {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
### Predictions

```{r}
newdat <- reactive({
  predict(mod,
          newdata = data.frame(word_count = input$a, 
                               section = input$b,
                               pub_hour  = input$c, 
                               dow = input$d))
})
renderTable({newdat})
```
````

I'm getting the following error:
`cannot coerce class "c("reactiveExpr", "reactive")" to a data.frame`

What can I do to fix this? If I want to plot `newdat` later (with something like `renderPlot({ggplot(newdat, yadayada)+geoms})`) will that be possible too?

Comment: Should be `renderTable({newdat()})` I think

Comment: That got me to a new error, which is fun. Now I'm getting `factor pub_hour has new level 0`.

Comment: Nevermind. That was an unrelated problem. Thank you very much, Chris!

Answer (score 2):

You are not calling the reactive expression of newdat in renderTable. Since you set it to be reactive, you need to use newdat():

```
renderTable({
newdat()
})
```